# curl -sSLO https://raw.githubusercontent.com && chmod +x install-fabric.sh curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 861)

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed curl, docker, and docker compose correctly, but while installing script I am getting this error. thanks in advance.

Same thing I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command you have run contains an incomplete URL for the **curl** command. According to the [Fabric install documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), you should be running:

```
curl -sSLO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/main/scripts/install-fabric.sh && chmod +x install-fabric.sh
```